# DTO entity mapping with hibernate @Version control

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using @Version annotation to provide version control in hibernate. My question is regarding the proper mapping of data from DTO to Entity.
What I feel is the right way is as follows but I want to know if there is a better way or this is how everybody does it.

- call comes to my service
- i load the entity to be updated (assume AddressEntity with version = 1)
- i map the AddressDTO values to AE, including sub-collections if any
- after all mapped, i detach the entity AE (only to be detached after Lazy sub collections mapped too)
- now i map the version from DTO to AE (as hibernate does not allow to update version in managed entity)
- now i call merge to update this detached AE entity

1) Is this the right way semantics and logic wise ?

2) (bit out of context) is there an overhead for hibernate to merge an object already in context and managed ie can i use merge for all updates safely irrespective or managed/unmanaged or Only merge+flush for unmanaged and flush for managed after updating some properties ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try to answer your question stepwise:

1. Suppose you have loaded an `AddressEntity (having id=123 and version=1)`. Set the property values from `AddressEntity` to `AddreeDto` including the `id` and `version` values. Send the `AddressDto` to UI.
2. Changes made to `AddresDto`. Call has come to your service. Create an instance of `AddressEntity` and set the values from `AddressDto` including the `id` and `version` values. This new `AddressEntity` has now turned into a detached instance, as it has a persistent identity, but its state is not guaranteed to be synchronized with database state.
3. Hibernate lets you reuse this `Addressentity` instance in a new transaction by reassociating it with a new persistence manager.This detached instance can be reassociated with a new Session by calling update(). You don't need to load the entity again.The update() method forces an update to the persistent state of the object in the database.

   Set the `addressEntity` properties:

   addressEntity.setId(dto.getId());
   addressEntity.setVersion(dto.getVersion());

   Attach `addressEntity` to a new session:

   Transaction tx = sessionTwo.beginTransaction();
   sessionTwo.update(addressEntity);

   tx.commit();
   sessionTwo.close();
4. The `session.update` will execute an SQL similar to this:

   update ADDRESS_ENTITY set ... , VERSION=2
   where ID=123 and VERSION=1
5. If another application transaction would have updated the same ADDRESS_ENTITY since it was loaded, the VERSION column would not contain the value 1, and the row would not be updated, and you will receive a `stale object state exception`. You can catch the exception and inform the User about the stale data.

Answer (score 0):

> - after all mapped, i detach the entity AE (only to be detached after Lazy sub collections mapped too)

Assuming you are performing this in a single transaction. Any persistent object that you have  retrieved from DB is associated with the current session and transaction context. If it is modified in the same transaction, its state will be automatically synchronized with the DB. This mechanism is called `automatic dirty checking`. It means Hibernate will track and save the changes made to an object inside a session.

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
int addressEntityID = 1234;
AddressEntity addressEntity = (AddressEntity) session.get(AddressEntity.class, new Long(addressEntityID));

// set the values from AddressDTO to AddressEntity
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

The object is retrieved from DB, it is modified and the modifications are propagated to DB on transaction commit.You don't need to detach and reattach an entity to perform an update.

> - now i map the version from DTO to AE (as hibernate does not allow to update version in managed entity)

The managed versioning is used to implement optimistic locking and the versioning of the entities is managed by Hibernate. The version number is just a counter value, it does not have any useful information that you should keep in your DTO.You don’t need to set the value of the version yourself. Hibernate will initialize the value when you first save an `AddressEntity`, and increment or reset it whenever the object is modified.

If another application transaction(T2) updates the persistent instance the same item since it was read by the current application transaction(T1), the T2 transaction will change the version value for this entity. Now when T1 tries to make an update, Hibernate will throw a `stale object state exception`, as the `version` of the entity has been changed. You can catch the `exception` and inform the User about the stale data. In particular, versioning prevents the lost update problem. You don't need to map the version from DTO to AE or from AE to DTO, as it does not have any meaningful information which can be used in contexts other than to implement optimistic locking.

Comment: you have not understood what i wanted to ask. i know all that you have specified. hibernate doesn't allow to set the version explicitly. take this case, i get AE v=1, send it to ui, ui updates some fields, i get it back, in this time, somebody else updated AE v=2, now my DTO has to know what the previous version was. so i get it back with v=1, try to map it n update n get stale object, coz DTO,entity had v=1 and DB has v=2 !
my question is about the process to map n update entity

Comment: yes.. i might have misunderstood your question. let me try to answer your question by adding a separate answer.